# How does this coordinate conversion achieve the desired result?

Tags: c#

The following code snippet, with `width=2`,`height=2`

```
int maxI = width + height;
for (int i = 1; i <= maxI; i++) {
    int startJ = Math.Max(0, i - width);
    int maxJ = Math.Min(i, height);
    for (int j = startJ; j <= maxJ; j++) {
        int x = i - j;
        int y = j;
        DoSomething(x,y);}}
```

Will call `DoSomething` with the following x,y pairs:

```
1: X=1,Y=0
2: X=0,Y=1          (Diagram: 0,0 
3: X=2,Y=0          at bottom left)
4: X=1,Y=1           5 7 8
5: X=0,Y=2           2 4 6
6: X=2,Y=1           @ 1 3
7: X=1,Y=2
8: X=2,Y=2
```

This is the desired result; to iterate a rectangle starting from 0,0 but expanding diagonally rather than (the much more popular) `[y*width+x]`. However, I'm baffled by the `maxI=width+height` and `x=i-j` calculations. How does this conversion work?

Comment: What exactly is it that baffles you? Your snippet shows only `int`s, so there's no conversion at all involved.

Comment: `i` iterates through the diagonals (excluding the upper left corner).  So `maxI` is the number of diagonals.  `j` iterates though the elements on the current diagonal.  So `maxJ` takes the current `i` and computes the number of elements in that diagonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to realize here is that x + y is a constant for each cell in a particular diagonal.  For example, cells 3, 4, and 5 have coordinates `{2, 0}; {1, 1}; {0, 2}`.  Notice that each of those add up to 2.

So `maxI` is really the maximum value of one of these sums.  Since `{width, height}` is the top right, the sum for that diagonal is `width + height`.  So that's where that comes from.

The `i - j` part comes about because it's basically solving the above equation.  Each value of `i` is the sum of the coordinates.  `j` is chosen to be the y-coordinate of a cell within that diagonal.  Since we know `x + y = i` and that `y = j`, we get that `x + j = i` or `x = i - j`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be also explained by geometric transformations:

1) Translation, so the rectangle's center is in origin:

```
x' = x - width/2
    bounds: [-width/2,width/2)

y' = y - height/2
    bounds: [-height/2,height/2)
```

2) Rotation by 45 degrees:

```
x'' = x'cos(45) - y'sin(45) = (sqrt(2)/2)x' - (sqrt(2)/2)y'
y'' = x'sin(45) + y'cos(45) = (sqrt(2)/2)x' + (sqrt(2)/2)y'
```

3) Scaling by `sqrt(2)/2`:

```
x''' = x' - y' = x - width/2 - y + height/2   
    bounds: [-width/2-height/2,width/2+height/2)

y''' = x' + y' = x - width/2 + y - height/2   
    bounds: [-width/2-height/2,width/2+height/2)
```

4) Translating back only on `x` axis:

```
x'''' = x''' + width/2 = x - y + height/2     
    bounds: [-height/2,width/2+height/2)

y'''' = y'''                                  
    bounds: [-width/2-height/2,width/2+height/2)
```

5) Introducing parametric variables:

```
i = y'''' + width/2 + height/2                
    bounds: [0,width+height)

j = x'''' + y'''' - width/2 - height/2        
    bounds: [-width-3*height/2,width/2+height/2)
```

For this transformation you get that:

```
x = i - j
y = j
```

And it will iterate point by point through diagonals going from bottom-right to top-left corner of the screen. `Max` and `Min` in the code you presented bound the result to a subset of these diagonals, representing a rectangle.